Difference Between google_maps_flutter on iOS and on Android
I have written a Flutter app for iOS and Android. It uses the google_maps_flutter plugin, which is working on both platforms.  There is a difference in behavior, though, between Android and iOS that I would like to understand and control.
On Android, when I touch a pin on the map in my application, two icons appear.  Pressing them navigates to Google Directions and to Google Maps respectively.  AFAIK I did not take any steps in my code to make these icons appear; it just happens by magic.
On iOS these two icons do not appear when I touch a pin.
How can I control this behavior?

Can you show us some code? "...it just happens by magic." I wish... OS behavior might be the reasons behind the change in UX. Is the code erroring out, or you are just seeing different behavior between OS?

Thank you very much for your reply, Viatech. Parth Viradiya's comment has helped understand this better.


Android: On Android, when you tap on a marker (pin) on the map, Google Maps automatically shows two action icons: - One for opening Google Maps directly. - One for getting directions.


iOS: On iOS, this automatic behavior does not happen by default. iOS doesn’t have the same integration for displaying additional action icons when interacting with map markers. Instead, it relies on your application code to define any custom behavior or context menus.


Controlling the Behavior


For Android: Automatic: This behavior is inherent to the Android platform and is managed by the OS and Google Maps. You have limited control over this automatic feature through the Flutter plugin.


For iOS: Custom Implementation: If you want similar functionality on iOS, you need to implement it yourself. You can use Flutter's showModalBottomSheet or showDialog to create a custom context menu when a user taps on a marker.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MyMapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyMapScreenState createState() => _MyMapScreenState();
}

class _MyMapScreenState extends State<MyMapScreen> {
  GoogleMapController? _mapController;
  final Marker _myMarker = Marker(
    markerId: MarkerId('my_marker'),
    position: LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194), // Example coordinates
    onTap: _onMarkerTapped,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(37.7749, -122.4194),
          zoom: 10,
        ),
        markers: {_myMarker},
        onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
          _mapController = controller;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onMarkerTapped() {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Container(
        height: 150,
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Open in Google Maps'),
              onTap: () {
                // Add your code to open Google Maps
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text('Get Directions'),
              onTap: () {
                // Add your code to get directions
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


Thanks very much for the explanation and the code, Parth.
